# A question about the conditional expected value

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The question is here, [image]

**Let R = XY and let A be the event X< 0.5. Evaluate E[R |A].**

And I know the the fX(x)[image]

**The given answer is here:**
The event A leaves us with a right triangle with a constant height. The conditional PDF is then 1/area =8. Theconditional expectationyields:
[image]

**And my solution is below:** [image]

There seems some difference between my answer and given answer... Why am I wrong? I check it for several times and do not know...

Thanks your help! ***I don't know how the type math symbols.. Sorry..***

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using the formula for a conditional probability where the condition is $X=x$.  However, the condition here is that $X<.5$.  Therefore, instead of using $x/2$ which is the $f(x)$ for a given $x$, use 1/16 which is the probability that $x<.5$.  This should get you the correct answer.

Comment: Yep..I know what you mean, but I integrate f(x) from 0 ~ 0.5.. Isn't that equivalent to the 1/16 ?( the integral of PDF is probability) @browngreen

Answer (score 0):

You may miss $f_{X|A}(x|A)$, which is $8x$. Note that $E[XY|A]=\int_{0}^{0.5}{E[XY|X=x]f_{X|A}(x|A)dx}$.